# Local type definition

Tags: typescript

I have several methods in which I pass a typed variable `T` and return the same typed array `T[]`.

I can declare `T` elsewhere, but I have several `T`s but each one is specific to only one method.

I can also declare the type `T` inside the method but then I can't use it in the method definition.

Is there a way to declare a type and bind it to the function only and also to be used inside it (in it's scope only).

Example

```
type T = { constraints?: { shouldPassT?: string } };
type V = { constraints?: { shouldPassV?: string } };

export class Test {
  public static validateShouldPassTest(): T[] {
    const errors: T[] = [];
    const error: T = { constraints: { shouldPassT: '' } };
    // some logic
    error.constraints.shouldPassT = 'bad' 
    errors.push(error);
    return errors;
  }

  public static validateShouldPassTest2(): V[] {
    const errors: V[] = [];
    const error: V = { constraints: { shouldPassV: '' } };
    // some logic
    error.constraints.shouldPassV = 'bad' 
    errors.push(error);
    return errors;
  }
}
```

But in fact as we don't like repetitions, I want something more specific as:

```
  public static validateShouldPassTest2(): V[] { // V here is infered from it's function scope only. This doesn't work but this is what I'm aiming for.
    type V = { constraints?: { shouldPassV?: string } };
    const errors: V[] = [];
    const error: V = { constraints: { shouldPassV: '' } };        // some logic
    error.constraints.shouldPassV = 'bad' 
    errors.push(error);
    return errors;
  }
}
```

Comment: "This doesn't work" Please [edit] to demonstrate exactly how it doesn't work (what happens when you do it, is there an error message, etc?)  Also please make the code a [mre] without undeclared things (what's `ValidationError`) or other code issues you're not asking about (if we paste it into our own IDEs with `--strict` compiler options, any errors should directly be about your question, not distractions from it.  e.g., you're indexing into a possibly undefined `constraints` property, and that's unsafe).  This will help make sure we're focused on the problem at hand.

Comment: I've got rid of `ValidationError` as it is irrelevant. Otherwise, I think I've put a reproducible code. The second snippets do not compile, and it is really clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to export a type name from a function scope so this is impossible.  There's a similar-ish feature request at [ms/TS#49427](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49427) asking for a way to automatically derive a type name for a function output type without declaring it, but even this is not part of the language.  You'll need to keep doing what you're doing now, I think